# radio button inside dropdown bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have this dropdown from bootstrap:

[image]

i insert radio button inside of the dropdown but if u can see the radio button inside dosnt have style, i want the same color when is showing the radio button inside of dropdown.

this is the html from dropdown:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown todos" id="todos">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle botn-todos" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Todos
            <span class="caret caret-posicion"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ancho-todos" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#" ><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="todoss"><span> Todos</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="enc"> En camino</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="enca"> En camino - 2do intento</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="entre"> Entregado</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="entre2"> Entregado al 2do intento</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="nose"> No se puede entregar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="cancelado"> Cancelado</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

and this is my script code when is clicking the item:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                alert(text);
                var htmlText = text + ' <span class="caret caret-posicion"></span>';
                $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
            });
```

this is the css for every radio button:

```
li:first-child input[type='radio']{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #6a706d;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #6a706d inset;*/
    }
    li:first-child input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:first-child input[type='radio']:checked:before {
        background:#6a706d;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #f1d04d;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
     margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }

    li:nth-child(2) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(2) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#f1d04d;
    }

    li:nth-child(3) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #caaf40;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #caaf40 inset;*/
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }

    li:nth-child(3) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(3) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#caaf40;
    }

    li:nth-child(4) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #92d04f;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #92d04f inset;*/
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }

    li:nth-child(4) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(4) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#92d04f;
    }

    li:nth-child(5) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #7aaf42;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #7aaf42 inset;*/
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }
    li:nth-child(5) input[type='radio']:hover {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #7aaf42 inset;
    }
    li:nth-child(5) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(5) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#7aaf42;
    }    

    li:nth-child(6) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #ed5850;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #b70218 inset;*/
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }

    li:nth-child(6) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(6) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#ed5850;
    }

    li:nth-child(7) input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #b70218;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #b70218 inset;*/
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }
    li:nth-child(7) input[type='radio']:before {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        width:60%;
        height:60%;
        margin: 20% auto;    
        border-radius:50%;    
    }
    li:nth-child(7) input[type='radio']:checked:before{
        background:#b70218;
    }
```

Comment: could you post css as well ?

Comment: If you made the CSS more generalistic it would be a nobrainer, but when you have CSS bound directly to specific elements i.e `li:nth-child(2)` and so on, you make it really hard for yourself.

Comment: I know it's not related to the question, but have you tried using this in a mobile browser with success? My radio buttons are not clickable in mobile browsers, and the drop down goes away.. Even if with code that prevents the dropdown from disappearing on click. TIA.